# Access folders outside war-package in Jelastic

Tags: java, tomcat, jelastic

I'm just starting to use Jelastic. I have a java web application which I have brought to Jelastic as a war-package and am running it on Tomcat. I have also a data folder which I want to keep separate from the war-package. Previously on my test environment as well as in Azure I have been able to access it by declaring it as a PreResource in context.xml-file. However, in Jelastic this does not seem to work. Should I use some other method or do I have an incorrect path? I did not see the absolute path anywhere so I had to ques that it is /opt/tomcat/webapps/data.

Thanks in advance,
Minna

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow
Please can you edit your question to include the non-working code/config?

Comment: user tomcat's server.xml file to store path

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.jelastic.com/environment-variables), Jelastic provides some preconfigured environment variables pointed to some useful directories on various Java nodes.

Specifically, on Tomcat 6, Tomcat 7, and TomEE servers, you have `user.home` (pointed to `/opt/tomcat/temp`) that can be used to write application data outside of your application (i.e. so those files are not lost on redeployment).

More recent Tomcat versions are provisioned as [docker based container images](https://docs.jelastic.com/dockers-overview) and for those you have the option to [define Docker variables](https://docs.jelastic.com/docker-variables) via the Jelastic dashboard, that you could point to any valid server path.

Tip: Make sure that your data path is set as a [docker volume](https://docs.jelastic.com/docker-volumes) to ensure that it is not lost during application server redeployment (e.g. if you change Tomcat or Java version in future, which is managed via creating a replacement container automatically transposing the defined 'volumes' - all other data is lost).